# How do I calculate gbm accuracy in R?

Tags: r, accuracy, boosting

I'm using gbm function in R. 
we can calculated the accuracy as using confusionMatrix() function in R.
But, before using this function, we have to split the data set as createDataPartition() function.

But! For using gbm function, we have to use full data set because it use full data and can make model that reinforce the weak observation.

Then... how to calculated gbm model's accuracy??? Do i have to split data set??
Or is there function that can calculate accuracy of gbm function??

Thanks for your reply. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

In this sense the GBM is similar to any other classification or prediction technique: first, we split the sample into train and test subsets, second, model using our training data, and third, calculate accuracy using test data. You can take a look at "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R" by G.James et al. (p. 330) to find an example of splitting the sample to fit boosted regression trees.